# Poissonization use for sample size

Tags: probability, statistics, approximation, poisson-distribution

(Cross-post from Stats Stack Exchange)

I'm interested in using the [Poissonization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163616/expected-rolls-to-get-3-of-any-number) [trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225152/expected-number-of-rolls-on-a-die-until-each-face-has-appeared-at-least-twice) to solve the following problem, which I made up:

> Suppose I have a categorical random variable $X$ taking values $1$,
> $2$, and $3$, with probability distribution $(\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3)$.
> How many samples from $X$ should I take before I have at least 5
> samples from one of the categories, with probability $.9$? Or at least 5 samples from every category?

If $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ are independent Poisson random variables with rates $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3$, then the Poissonization trick tells us that $(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3 \mid \sum Y_i = k)$ has distribution $\sim \operatorname{Mult}(k; \pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3)$ on $\mathbb{N}^3$.

If $A\subset \mathbb{N}^3$ is the set $\{x_1, x_2, x_3 \leq 4\}$ (I'm interested in the complement of $A$), then $$\mathbb{P}\{(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3)\in A\}$$
$$ = \sum \mathbb{P}\{(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3)\in A \mid \sum Y_i =k \} \cdot \mathbb{P}(\sum Y_i = k)$$

And (this is where I get a bit shaky) I should expand in a sort of fake variable $\lambda$, representing the rate of $Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3$ (though I know that rate is actually one), and then $\mathbb{P}\{(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3)\in A\}$ is

$$e^{\pi_1 \lambda}(1 + \frac{(\pi_1\lambda)^1}{1!} + \dotsb + \frac{(\pi_1\lambda)^4}{4!})\, \cdot \, $$
$$e^{\pi_2 \lambda}(1 + \frac{(\pi_2\lambda)^1}{1!} + \dotsb + \frac{(\pi_2\lambda)^4}{4!})\, \cdot \,  $$
$$e^{\pi_3 \lambda}(1 + \frac{(\pi_3\lambda)^1}{1!} + \dotsb + \frac{(\pi_3\lambda)^4}{4!})\, \cdot \,  $$

And now I should multiply this by $e^{-\lambda}$, expand in $\lambda$ somehow, and look for the coefficient on $\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$? Is that right?

Comment: The $\lambda$ enters if you assume $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ independent Poisson r.v. with rates $\lambda\pi_1,\lambda\pi_2,\lambda\pi_3$. Then $\sum Y_i$ is a Poisson r.v. with rate $\lambda$.

Comment: The rest of what you say is correct and will allow you to find a formula for $\mathbb{P}\{(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3)\in A \mid \sum Y_i =k \}$.